# My development server report this error after running it

Tags: python, django, web, backend

## My django project reports an error after running the development server:

I get this error each time I run the development server:
Virtual environment was activated before running the server.
How do I resolve it and get my project working again?

```
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\bello\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "c:\users\bello\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
        raise _exception[1]
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
        autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "c:\users\bello\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\bello\Desktop\DESKTOP\EDX\mosque-around-you\mosque-around-you\mosquesinlocation\models.py", line 3, in <module>
        from cities_light.models import City, Region as State, Country
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\cities_light\models.py", line 83, in <module>
        from .abstract_models import (AbstractCountry, AbstractRegion,
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\cities_light\abstract_models.py", line 5, in <module>
        import autoslug
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\autoslug\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from autoslug.fields import AutoSlugField
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\autoslug\fields.py", line 29, in <module>
        from autoslug.settings import slugify, autoslug_modeltranslation_enable
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\autoslug\settings.py", line 68, in <module>
        slugify = get_callable(slugify_function_path)
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\django\urls\utils.py", line 28, in get_callable
        mod = import_module(mod_name)
      File "c:\users\bello\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "C:\Users\bello\Envs\mosque-around-you\lib\site-packages\autoslug\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
        from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist, DateField
    ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist'
```

Comment: `FieldDoesNotExist` is in [`django.core.exceptions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/exceptions/). Are you trying to use that yourself? If not, you may have installed a library that isn't compatible with the version of Django you're using.

Comment: How do I figure out the library causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update `django-autoslug` from version `<= 1.9.7` to version `1.9.8` as Django `3.1` dropped `FieldDoesNotExist` reimport from `django.db.models.fields`

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id1)

> The compatibility import of django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist
> in django.db.models.fields is removed.

Comment: I have already upgraded django-autoslug to version 1.9.8 but the problem persists. Thanks for the rescue effort

Comment: This should not be the case as this error is clearly fixed in https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug/blob/v1.9.8/autoslug/utils.py#L15 You might have similar error in different package or you did not update environment correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem based on the hints proposed by upgrading the django-cities-light package from version 3.6.0 to 3.8.1

Thanks a lot